# Correlation plots for non square correlation matrix with significance stars

Tags: r, matrix, plot, correlation, r-corrplot

I computed several non square correlation matrixes now I want to plot them. I found several packages to do so like `corrplot` and `corrgram`, but I can only get them to work with square matrixes. What are the correct parameters for non square matrixes?

My tries so far:

```
library(psych)
x <- psych::corr.test(P19[2:ncol(P19)], motivation_on[2:ncol(motivation_on)], method = "spearman")


xoxo <- as.data.frame(x[1])
library(corrplot)
corrplot(xoxo, method = "number")
```

The goal is to have a plot like in this post including significance stars:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/correlograms-are-correlicious/

PS: My correlation matrix looks like this, note that I do not correlate the vars within the dataframes to avoid a giant matrix:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `is.corr` variable:

```
library(corrplot)

corrplot(xoxo, method="number", is.corr=FALSE)
```